# asus server install issue

Tags: system-installation

ok so I built a system with a dual cpu board and 16 gig ddr4 per cpu.  the board is an asus z10pa-D8, the cpus are intel xeon e5 2620 v3 6 cores. I'm running mem86 to test the ram right now.  the issue that I'm having is that when I try to install ubuntu server 14.04.1 (tryed over network, and through usb) the system will freeze when i get to the hdd install. when i check the usb if there is an error with the install disk i get that there is one. that is why i when to the network install but that fails at the same point. if anyone can give me a hand with it that would be magical. the install crash is no longer in the same spot, it changes every time i try.

so, i think it's an  install error, because i installed windows 7 on the rig just fine but ubuntu still keeps crashing during install.

Comment: im not using a cd-rom, i dont have a cd drive in my server :)

Comment: i also passed my mem86 test, but im going to keep running it till i figure out why it wont install

Comment: I know a little about it,(only from rooting phone) but i dont know how to check it

Comment: Did you get it to work - i have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

A feaw guesses/checks

1. Make sure you don't have any raid functionality enabled in the bios.
   Linux doesn't play well with software raid, nor with intel matrix store ssd cache solution. You need to set your disks in plain sata/AHCI mode with uefi boot.
2. Make sure your usb stick also boots in uefi, not legacy. If the boot env doesn't see uefi, then it will assume you want a legacy system, which is sometimes broken on newer rigs.
3. Make sure you make an uefi partition, when you format. If you don't then the system installs fine, and when you reboot, it will not boot.

Comment: i cant even get the install to go past select which drive would you like to install on